# Why can't I insert objects into a map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

So i have a function that  is supposed to return a following map:
 `map<MyObj*, Datastruct>`

While trying to insert object from a list which contains said objects:

```
for(auto element: myList){  
    Datastruct str;  
    str.property1 = element.property1;  
    str.property2 = element.property2;  
    saidMap.insert(element.PointerToMyObj, str);  
}
```

Objects in *myList* contain a pointer to myObj and some properties i need to move from list to a map. Having executed this code in a function below:

`map<MyObj*, Datastruct> listToMap = convertList(myList);`

I get yelled at by the compiler that:

> "no matching function to call to 'std::map::insert(MyObj*&, Datastruct&)"

Here i am helpless. I don't know why compiler would show that i am trying to pass a reference to the function if *element* in myList(see above) contains

> MyObj *PointerToMyObj;

which, the way i see it, is a correct type to pass to the insert function right?
I also tried with

> std::make_pair

whereupon compiler yells at me for trying to insert a pair into a
`map<MyObj*, Datastruct>.`

I am utterly lost. Could someone explain to me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for improperly formatting code in this question, StackOverflow would not allow me to post it yelling at me for "indent 4 spaces or press ctrl+k" which i tried to no avail. It's not my day i guess.

Comment: You copy the text of the code from your IDE, select it and press ctrl+k or use the {} button. If that still does not format correctly use the site: http://format.krzaq.cc/ to reformat then paste and select it and press ctrl+k or use the {} button

Comment: What was the error with the pair attempt? Have you checked [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) instead of guessing?

Comment: The error was: "no matching function for call to std::map<MyObj*, Datastruct>::insert(std::pair<MyObj*, Datastruct>"

Comment: tip: dont panic, but rtfm (read-the-fine-manual). Insert indeed has no overload for the parameters you pass, though it has others: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: tip2: dont get confused by the reference in the error message, thats always part of the error message, when the compiler cannot find a matching overload

Comment: show your attempt of inserting a pair, that should work, but you need to show the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map's value type is not

```
std::pair<MyObj*, Datastruct>
```

but

```
std::pair<MyObj* const, Datastruct>
```

Presumably you hardcoded the pair type somewhere, but missed out the `const`.

Or, if you wrote `saidMap.insert(std::make_pair(element.PointerToMyObj, str))` then that should have worked and something else is wrong in your code.

---

But it's much easier to use [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
saidMap.emplace(element.PointerToMyObj, str);
```

This C++11 version of [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) has all the magic machinery needed to make that work "transparently".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *almost* alright. You're getting this compiler error because `map::insert` really doesn't have such overload. It's a tiny detail you've missed on reading up when looking at the `std::map` documentation. It is so that `map::insert` doesn't work as implicit constructor, which is how you are trying to use it in the pasted code.
This is something you can achieve by emplacing - `map::emplace`:

```cpp
for(auto element : myList){  
  Datastruct str;  
  str.property1 = element.property1;  
  str.property2 = element.property2;  
  saidMap.emplace(element.PointerToMyObj, str);
}
```

Using `map::insert()`: The insert function is used to insert the ***key-value*** **pair** in the map and has 3 *general* overloads, in fact, they are more, but these are the main ideas behind how to insert in a map.

- insert(pair): simply inserts a new pair in the map, where pair.first is the `key` and pair.second is the `value`. Only happens when the key is not already in the map.
- insert(it, pair): insert using an iterator and a pair, where `it` is a pointer to the location where you want to insert your pair at.
- insert(begin, end): used for copying the elements from another map by accepting iterators to `begin` and `end` of the map.

In your case, you've missed the to actually pass a `pair`. You can construct it inside of the insert argument list as follows:

```cpp
for(auto element : myList){  
  Datastruct str;  
  str.property1 = element.property1;  
  str.property2 = element.property2;  
  saidMap.insert( /*implicitly derive a pair as:*/ { element.PointerToMyObj, str } );
}
```

**Note:** This is a *post-C++11* functionality, so make sure you're setting compiler's C++ version to at least that.

I've reproduced your code with the working version of the `map::insert` in **Compiler Explorer (godbolt)** for you have a look (in both `gcc` and `clang` compilers): https://godbolt.org/z/7Mqut0.

Hope this helps!